# Where is documentation for multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.6, python-multiprocessing

There is frighteningly little strict API documentation (read: **ZERO**) for `multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult`. The multiprocessing explanation doc talks *about* `ApplyResult`s, but does not define them.

The same appears to apply to `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, although the Python multiprocessing guide appears to cover it better.

Even the `ApplyResult` `help()` results are paltry:

```
 |  get(self, timeout=None)
 |  
 |  ready(self)
 |  
 |  successful(self)
 |  
 |  wait(self, timeout=None)
```

- `Get()` and `Ready()` I get. Those are fine.
- I have absolutely no idea what `wait()` is for, given that you are
  dealing with a "pool", which one would assume would waits for you in
  the `get()` call. Is this "wait for the result, but don't get it now" Or is it an OS-style wait? And if so, what would that even *mean*?
- I am equally unsure of what `successful()` is all about.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're right that there is in a glitch in the documentation: the class is actually documented as [AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult), not ApplyResult.  The two are different names for the same class:

```
>>> multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult is multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult
True
```

The name may have been changed at some point and the docs weren't consistently updated, but everything is documented, it's just documented under the wrong name.  (There is [a closed bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue17805) in which someone pointed out that the docs mention AsyncResult but the class is actually called ApplyResult, so they added AsyncResult as an alias.)

Comment: Doc to be found at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see from the code:

- `ready()`: returns true if the task run by the "thread" is ready to return a result
- `get(timeout=None)`: waits for a result for timeout units (in floating-point seconds) and returns the result on a successful completion. On timeout raises a `TimeoutError`, on a non-successful completion raises the associated exception.
- `wait(timeout=None)`: waits on a condition variable set by the worker "thread", as per `threading.Condition.wait([timeout])` ***DOES NOT IMPLY*** reaping of the child "thread".
- `successful()`: if `ready`, returns `True` if the result of `get()` will be a value. Otherwise, returns `False` (i.e. the result will be an exception). If assertions are enabled, will raise ValueError if the result is not ready.